# How to change Gatsby Link text with getProps and setState

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, setstate, use-effect, use-state

The header.js of my Gatsby website contains a simple navigation with a logo and a link. If the About Page is active:

- Link text should change from "About" to "Close"
- Link URL should change from "/about" to "/"

See the code of the header.js below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

export default function Header() {
  const [aboutLink, setAboutLink] = useState({
    title: "About",
    url: "/about",
  })

  const closeLink = {
    title: "Close",
    url: "/",
  }

  const isActive = ({ isCurrent }) => {
    return isCurrent && setAboutLink(closeLink)
  }

  return (
    <div id="header">
      <Link to="/">My Website</Link>
      <Link getProps={isActive} to={aboutLink.url}>{aboutLink.title}</Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I tried to achieve this with `setState` and it seems to work. But not properly because I'm also getting this error in the console:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`Header`) while rendering a different component (`Context.Consumer`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Context.Consumer`, follow the stack trace as described in https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18178#issuecomment-595846312
    in Location (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Link (created by GatsbyLink)
    in GatsbyLink (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Location (created by GatsbyLinkLocationWrapper)
    in GatsbyLinkLocationWrapper (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (at header.js:22)
    in div (at header.js:20)
    in Header (at layout.js:8)
    in div (at layout.js:7)
    in Layout (at about.js:21)
    in About (created by HotExportedAbout)
    in AppContainer (created by HotExportedAbout)
    in HotExportedAbout (created by PageRenderer)
    in PageRenderer (at query-result-store.js:90)
    in PageQueryStore (at root.js:58)
    in RouteHandler (at root.js:80)
    in div (created by FocusHandlerImpl)
    in FocusHandlerImpl (created by Context.Consumer)
    in FocusHandler (created by RouterImpl)
    in RouterImpl (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Location (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Router (at root.js:75)
    in ScrollHandler (at root.js:71)
    in RouteUpdates (at root.js:70)
    in EnsureResources (at root.js:68)
    in LocationHandler (at root.js:126)
    in LocationProvider (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Location (at root.js:125)
    in Root (at root.js:134)
    in StaticQueryStore (at root.js:150)
    in ConditionalFastRefreshOverlay (at root.js:149)
    in _default (at app.js:165)
```

I can't figure it out. If I use `useEffect` like in this example https://flaviocopes.com/react-update-while-rendering-different-component/ I'm getting this error: `'isActive' is not defined`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const isActive = ({ isCurrent }) => {
    return isCurrent && setAboutLink(closeLink)
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi - did you find a solution to this? The answers below weren't that helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `isActive` property for `isCurrent` or alternatively, use the `isPartiallyCurrent`, as you can see from the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/#use-getprops-for-advanced-link-styling):

> Gatsby’s `<Link>` component comes with a `getProps` prop, which can be
> useful for advanced styling. It passes you an object with the
> following properties:
>
> - `isCurrent` — true if the `location.pathname` is exactly the same as the
>   `<Link>` component’s to prop
> - `isPartiallyCurrent` — `true` if the
>   `location.pathname` starts with the `<Link>` component’s to prop
> - `href` —
>   the value of the to `prop`
> - `location` — the page’s `location` object
>
> You can read more about it on [`@reach/router`’s documentation](https://reach.tech/router/api/Link).

Related topics:

- [Gatsby Link not working with isPartially Active on MDX rendered pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70946740/gatsby-link-not-working-with-ispartially-active-on-mdx-rendered-pages)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it out but I'm still having the same issue:  
  
warning: 'isActive' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars  
error: 'isActive' is not defined  
warning: Cannot update a component (`Header`) while rendering a different component (`Context.Consumer`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Context.Consumer`, follow the stack trace as described in …

Comment: I think you want to use `isCurrent` instead of `isActive`: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/#use-getprops-for-advanced-link-styling